# Javascript next or previous button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is My Model When i click my model

```
<div class="modal fade" id="checkoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="checkoutModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="checkoutModalLabel">Shipping Address</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
              <form action="thankYou.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
```

This tag tall every problem and there is background color call passed

```
<p class="bg-danger" id="payment-errors"></p>
```

This is the problem

There was Step 1 div open wher i click next then not going next div in step 2 as like pill type

```
<div id="step1" style="display: block;">
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="full_name">Full Name:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="full_name" name="full_name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="email">Email :</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="street">Street Address:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="street" name="street" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="street2">Street Address 2:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="street2" name="street2" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="city">City :</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="state">State :</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="state" name="state" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="country">Country:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="country" name="country" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

When click next this div not open  some error and this error up

```
            <div id="step2" style="display: none;"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check_address();">Next >></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the button function work i think may help you

```
<script>
    function check_address(){
        var data = {
            'full_name' : jQuery('#full_name').val(),
            'email' : jQuery('#email').val(),
            'street' : jQuery('#street').val(),
            'street2' : jQuery('#street2').val(),
            'city' : jQuery('#city').val(),
            'state' : jQuery('#state').val(),
            'zip_code' : jQuery('#zip_code').val(),
            'country' : jQuery('#country').val()
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
           url : '/ecommerce/admin/parsers/check_address.php',
            method : 'POST',
            data : data,
            success : function(data){
                if(data != 'passed'){
                    jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data);
                }
                if(data == 'passed'){
                    alert('Passed!');
                }
            },
            error : function (){alert("Something Went Wrong");}
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is another page link and this is check file for java script file

```
<?php
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ecommerce/connection/init.php';
    $name = sanitize($_POST['full_name']);
    $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
    $street = sanitize($_POST['street']);
    $street2 = sanitize($_POST['street2']);
    $city = sanitize($_POST['city']);
    $state = sanitize($_POST['state']);
    $zip_code = sanitize($_POST['zip_code']);
    $country = sanitize($_POST['country']);

    $errors = array();

    $required = array (
        'full_name'     => 'Full Name',
        'email'         => 'Email',
        'street'        => 'Street Address',
        'city'          => 'City',
        'state'         => 'State',
        'zip_code'      => 'Zip Code',
        'country'       => 'Country',
    );

//All field is Required

    foreach($required as $f => $d){
        if(empty($_POST[$f]) || $_POST[$f] == ''){
            $errors[] = $d.' is required.';
        }
    }
// Valid Email Address

if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errors[] = 'Please Enter a valid Email.';
}
if(!empty($errors)){
    echo display_errors($errors);
}else{
    echo 'passed';
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: sir can i give you my source code then solve this.......

Comment: Are you using `twitter-bootstrap`

Comment: yes sir @AA Shakil